# How to make stream report error and next

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I have a stream which always reports onNext.
I would like to check the object and decide whether to send it in onNext or to send it in onError.

should i create my own Throwable class which holds this object and throw this Throwable inside the map operator? or is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest, you can `throw` an exception and have `map()` catch the exception and redirect to `onError()`. This is useful when the error might happen deep within the mapping code.

The other way, that doesn't require `throw` is to use `flatMap()`:

```
...
.flatMap( input -> {
                     if ( input.isValid() ) {
                       return Observable.just( mapValue( input ) );
                     }
                     return Observable.error( new MyThrowable( input ) );
                   } )
...
```

To my eye, there is less discontinuity because you know for a fact that one of your options at the top level is to encounter an error.